# LinearLayout height not getting set programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app, I've a layout like:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/belowAcionBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

I need to set the height of `LinearLayout belowAcionBar` dynamically. This view needs to be shown just below `ActionBar`.

To set the height I'm using below code:

```
View panelView = findViewById(R.id.belowAcionBar); // This gives object of LinearLayout
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) panelView.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 48; // In dp
panelView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

**Issue 1:**

Since `belowAcionBar` is a `LinearLayout`, first I tried of using `LayoutParams` as `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`, rather than `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`.
But it thre a runtime error `Can't cast FrameLayout.LayoutParams to LinearLayout.LayoutParams`.

Why it is getting `panelView.getLayoutParams()` as `FrameLayout`?

**Issue 2:**

Even after using code above, my view `belowAcionBar` is appearing to be much less than `48dp`. Seems like it is being partially hidden behind `ActionBar`.

**Issue 3:**

If I change the layout to:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/belowAcionBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/purple_dark" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

And change the java code to:

```
View panelView = findViewById(R.id.belowAcionBar); 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) panelView.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 48; // In dp
panelView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Then my code works perfectly, but adds extra Layout. Why it is working now?

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: 1 - You were using FrameLayout.LayoutParams instead of LinearLayout.LayoutParams. 2 - You're working in px, not in dp, should scale accordingly to your device's resolution. 3 - The extra layout isn't really needed